# How to freeze field-values in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to make sure that the values of certain required fields can not be changed later on. Is there a way to define this on the schema level?

Currently, I'm thinking about implementing this using a Record Trigger to raise an exception if a value change is noticed but this feels clunky.

E.g.:

```
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
     IF (NEW.product_id !== OLD.product_id) THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Attempt to change frozen field "product_id" on UPDATE.'
     END IF;
  END IF; 
END
```

Comment: Why do you need this? I mean, what's problem if  just not use `update` queries  for that columns ?

Comment: Rather define the asserts once. Otherwise burden is on the client developer. Ie more risk

Comment: The less clunky solution would be to remove `UPDATE` permissions from this field via `GRANT`/`REVOKE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a trigger with comparison on a field, you can save execution by specifying condition on the [trigger itself](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html):

> A Boolean expression that determines whether the trigger function will
>   actually be executed. If WHEN is specified, the function will only be
>   called if the condition returns true. In FOR EACH ROW triggers, the
>   WHEN condition can refer to columns of the old and/or new row values
>   by writing OLD.column_name or NEW.column_name respectively. Of course,
>   INSERT triggers cannot refer to OLD and DELETE triggers cannot refer
>   to NEW.

eg:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.product_id IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.product_id)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_account_update();
```

Of course it does not freeze anything. Now you cant change it with update, unless you disable the trigger, update and enable trigger back. But at least later requires alter table, not just update